# How to remove an untitled/id'ed element and change another parent elements properties?

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage accessed via a lan connection for a screen sharing service that offers a form of a control panel that is unnecessary for functionality and reduces the size of the screen being shared. I have been manually editing the elements via chrome's inspection panels to remove said control panel and maximize the shared screen's size and placement.

Being unfamiliar with javascript I have attempted to use the get elementByID and parentNode functionalities however the attempts to remove the element always failed.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ScreenStream</title>
    </head>
    <frameset cols="208px, *" frameborder="1">
        <div id="i4c-draggable-container" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1499; width: 0px; height: 0px;">
            <div data-reactroot="" class="resolved" style="all: initial;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <frameset rows="15%, 208px, *">
            <frame src="1" name="frHeader" scrolling="auto" noresize="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
            <frame src="2" name="frCamera" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
            <frame src="3" name="frControl" scrolling="no" noresize="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        </frameset>
        <frame src="4" scrolling="auto" name="frScreen" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <div id="i4c-dialogs-container">
        </div>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

I have been deleting the "`<frameset rows="15%, 208px, *">`" element by hand, and changing the "`<frameset cols="208px, *" frameborder="1">`" to "`cols=100%`" and it has worked for my purpose however I was looking to create a bookmark with a javascript:(function) to automate the process.

Comment: Something like this would work. Try it out `document.querySelector('frameset[rows="15%, 208px, *"]').remove(); document.querySelector('frameset[cols="208px, *"]').setAttribute('cols', '100%');`

Comment: What is your chrome version ?

Comment: I ran it through a bookmarklet creator script and the result worked well although i would have never stumbled upon it on my own.  
`javascript:(function()%7Bdocument.querySelector('frameset%5Brows%3D%2215%25%2C%20208px%2C%20*%22%5D').remove()%3B%20document.querySelector('frameset%5Bcols%3D%22208px%2C%20*%22%5D').setAttribute('cols'%2C%20'100%25')%7D)()`

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:(function()%7Bdocument.querySelector('frameset%5Brows%3D%2215%25%2C%20208px%2C%20*%22%5D').remove()%3B%20document.querySelector('frameset%5Bcols%3D%22208px%2C%20*%22%5D').setAttribute('cols'%2C%20'100%25')%7D)()
```

Following the advice of Panther I managed to identify functioning lines of javascript to allow the selection of the needed framesets. With some testing on my end it appears that Chrome wanted to operate within a set formatting and required me to run the code through [Mr.Coles' Bookmarklet Creator](https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/).